# How to fetch a category of the next post in the wp_query loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check if current post in the loop has the same category that the next one.

```
while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
        if(category_of_this_post == category_of_the_next_post) //this
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: instead of above,do get post by category and create an array for that. all post of same category will come in single-child-array.

Comment: the problem is that I really need to do it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough setup is the following.

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $next                 = $query->posts[ $query->current_post + 1];
    $current_categories   = get_the_category();
    $next_post_categories = get_the_category($next->ID);

    if ( /* compare $current_categories  $next_post_categories */ ) {

    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); // always reset
```

A few things to keep in mind:

- You can assign multiple categories, so think about how you want to compare
- On the last post you will get an notice. because it does not exist. Build a check for that.

Comment: @SaintBurrito if this is the correct answer please mark it as so.

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me in the past to keep previous and next in the same cat:

```
 <?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="prev"><< Previous Post</span>', 'esquire' ), TRUE ); ?>
 <?php next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="prev">Next Post >></span>', 'esquire' ), TRUE ); ?>
```

Comment: I'm looping through all the post, they are grouped by category, and when the next post is from different category than current one I just want to display something and keep the loop going